# Exclude words on shopify from google translate

Tags: shopify, google-translate, google-merchant-center

I am looking for a solution to exclude the email info@vanea-barfussschuhe.com from translating when using Google Translate on the entire shopify store. The reason is, it becomes info@vanea-barfussschuh.com and does not match the data in GMC (google merchant center), which results in a policy violation… I am using the Sense theme from Shopify.

[english, incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBQiT.png)

[german, correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CueLa.png)

I have already tried the following, but none worked or maybe I did it incorrectly, I have limited experience but I must resolve this, so any help would be highly appreciated.

1. Writing the address as an HTML entity info@vanea-barfussschuhe.com
2. Adding the class “no translate” in the different .json shopify files, always came back with an error “unexpected token”...

Answer (score 0):

> You can now add class="notranslate" to any HTML element to prevent
> that element from being translated.

[Google Search Blog](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2008/10/helping-you-break-language-barrier)

First and easy option is to add a new section of type **liquid-code** on homepage and render custom HTML markup with notranslate class. Something like

```
<h4 class="notranslate">✉ info@vanea-barfussschuhe.com</h4>
```

Second option is to edit the section file and add notranslate class. For that,

Edit theme code -> sections -> rich-text.liquid

Line 45-55 is what renders the rich text field that you are using.

```
{%- when 'text' -%}
  <div class="rich-text__text rte{% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %} scroll-trigger animate--slide-in{% endif %}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}
    {% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %}
      data-cascade
      style="--animation-order: {{ forloop.index }};"
      {% endif %}
  >
    {{ block.settings.text }}
  </div>
```

Add notranslate class like this and rest of the code should remain same.

```
{%- when 'text' -%}
  <div class="notranslate rich-text__text rte{% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %} scroll-trigger animate--slide-in{% endif %}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}
    {% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %}
      data-cascade
      style="--animation-order: {{ forloop.index }};"
      {% endif %}
  >
    {{ block.settings.text }}
  </div>
```

However, this will make all the rich content fields in rich-text section non translatable.

Ideal solution is to add a new type of field in this section that allow you to control the markup or something.